james not adding the dkim header
i have been trying to setup James email server from Apache today and my problem with it has been that it refuses to add the dkim headers to my emails although i thought that i have configured for it.
here is what i did
so this is my current mailetcontainer.xml
<processor name="transport" state="relay" enableJmx="true">
    <mailet match="All" class="org.apache.james.jdkim.mailets.DKIMSign">
    <signatureTemplate>v=1; s=default; d=aktimail.com; c=relaxed/relaxed; h=Message-ID:Date:Subject:From:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; a=rsa-sha256; bh=; b=;<signatureTemplate>
<privateKey>-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</privateKey>
    </mailet>
</processor>



Solved: DKIM Signing with Apache James Configuration Issue
Hey, possible future dev!
I have solved the problem and still decided to post here as one should
The main issue was that I didn’t fully understand how the configuration logic worked. Here's the corrected configuration:
<processor state="relay" enableJmx="true">
    <mailet match="All" class="org.apache.james.jdkim.mailets.DKIMSign">
        <signatureTemplate>v=1; s=(same thing here with the dns record); d=dom.com; h=Message-ID:Date:Subject:From:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; a=rsa-sha256; bh=; b=;c=relaxed/relaxed;</signatureTemplate>
        <privateKey>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[key here no gaps don't remove the begin and end]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
        </privateKey>
    </mailet>

    <mailet match="All" class="RemoteDelivery">
        <outgoingQueue>outgoing</outgoingQueue>
        <delayTime>5000, 100000, 500000</delayTime>
        <maxRetries>3</maxRetries>
        <maxDnsProblemRetries>0</maxDnsProblemRetries>
        <deliveryThreads>10</deliveryThreads>
        <sendpartial>true</sendpartial>
        <bounceProcessor>bounces</bounceProcessor>
    </mailet>
</processor>

yeah do it this way and it fixes because they need to be connected or something idk
